# sql readability INNER JOIN ON

Tags: sql, code-readability

For sql readability I am wondering what is the best way to to structure my `INNER JOIN`s. Looking I see a slew of different methods at my orginization.

## 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id
```

## 2

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.foo_id
```

is #1 or #2 the most accepted method? I am leaning toward #1.

Comment: Personally I prefer #2 because it declares how the new thing relates to the existing stuff. But this is really going to be a pointless opinionated discussion.

Comment: I prefer to remove the `inner` keyword completely to reduce noise, and to indent the join part

Comment: This wil quickly turn into a discussion over style preference, and hence off-topic for SO

Comment: @HoneyBadger, is there a better place we can migrate this to in the stack exchange?

Comment: I prefer #1 and like the explicit INNER JOIN, in my defence I started out writing mainframe COBOL so like upper case wordiness.

Comment: We can all have preferences but if your company has a standard, follow that :)

Answer (score 1):

I always use the first method.

[Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) and [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) too :

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
     INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p
     ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY p.LastName


SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2p, as it's entirely a matter of personal preference.

```
SELECT
   Field1,
   Field2,
   MAX(Field3)
FROM
   FirstTable ft
INNER JOIN
   SecondTable st
ON ft.Id = st.FirstTableId
WHERE
   Clause = 'value'
GROUP BY
   Field3
```